# Rythm Template Engine and GAE reload template without restart (dev mode)

Tags: google-app-engine, development-environment, rythm

In Google App Engine (development server), it is posible to reload a Rythm template when changed? I'am configuring RythmEngine with engine.file_write.enabled=true and engine.mode=prod to avoid file permission errors, but every time I change a template y have to restart the GAE server.

Answer (score 0):

When `engine.mode` is `prod` it will not reload template. If you want template reload you need to have `engine.mode` set to `dev`. However on GAE you need to configure `engine.file_write.enabled` to `false` to avoid file permission error

Comment: I have set `engine.mode=dev` and `engine.file_write.enabled=false`, but every time i try to render a template the server throws `java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.`. Could be when running in dev mode rythm always try to write to filesystem ignoring `engine.file_write.enabled`.

Comment: then it should be a bug. Can you please submit an issue on github? paste the error stack of `java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class` issue